# I Can use a custom Swiftlint Instalation path on xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, linux-mint, swiftlint

I need to install swiftlint with mint on my mac, on the path user/.mint/bin, but xcode dont recognize the installation i can use a custom path xcode swiftlint configuration ?

I added a default image from the conf below.
[image]

Comment: `sudo gem install cocoapods`, `pod 'SwiftLint'` for xcode project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before checking for `swiftlint`, your script needs to update the local PATH:

```
export PATH=${HOME}/.mint/bin:${PATH}
# Rest of script
```